# Combining a huge list of dataframes into a one dataframe without getting a memory error?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a huge list of dataframe(time-series)(over 5500 entries in a list and 750 x 2 size of each entry). How do I combine it into a single dataframe without getting a memory error?

I tried using pandas.merge, pandas.concat but nothing is working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A memory error suggests that your system is running out of memory at some point. It sounds like your dataset is just too large for your system to hold in memory at once.

Comment: **run on a system with more memory**, you may update your question with your code, sample input, sample output, expected output... and anything else which is relevant to your particular questions. As it stands it is not really clear what you expect from us, with the minimum information given.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply any code so I don't know what your setup looks like, but consider the concept below.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                    'B': ['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                    'D': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                    index=[4, 5, 6, 7])


df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11'],
                    'B': ['B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11'],
                    'C': ['C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11'],
                    'D': ['D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'D11']},
                    index=[8, 9, 10, 11])


frames = [df1, df2, df3]

result = pd.concat(frames)
print(result)
```